# Regex for extract first character of word (Ultisnips)

Tags: regex, vim, ultisnips

I am attempting to use the Ultisnips Vim plugin to replace a word with its first character, transformed to lowercase (anong other things that aren't relevant to the question).  For illustration, I wish to write a snippet

```
snippet 
$1 ${1/ WHAT TO PUT HERE / AND HERE /}
endsnippet
```

which would output

```
Word w
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it:

```
snippet w
$1 ${1/(.).*/\l$1/}
endsnippet
```

Please note that the replacement strings use Python regexps and syntax, not VimL.

Another way (cleaner, IMO):

```
snippet w
$1 `!p snip.rv=t[1][0:1].lower()`
endsnippet
```